# How Would You Attach the Same Uploaded File to Several SP2019 List Items Using C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, application-pages

I have a form on a .Net application page that allows a user to apply to multiple open positions at once with an attached resume.

I need to be able to attach the resume to each SP list item that is created. Each selected position creates a new row in the list.

*** I figured it out, I just haven't seen a solution online and wanted to see if others have a better solution. ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm checking a GridView checkbox for Job Listings selected and loading them into an array.

```
bool atLeastOneRowSelected = false;
var IDs = new List<int>();

foreach (GridViewRow row in gvPositions.Rows)
{
    // Access the CheckBox
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cbJob");
    if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
    {
        // Delete row! (Well, not really...)
        atLeastOneRowSelected = true;
        // First, get the ProductID for the selected row
        IDs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(gvPositions.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value));

    }
}
```

Next, I create the SharePoint list items and save the internal ID into another array, which I will reference next to add the resume attachment.

```
List<int> intIDs = new List<int>();

SPList list = site.Lists["Candidates"];

SPListItem listItem = list.AddItem();
listItem.Update();

intIDs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(listItem["ID"].ToString()));
```

Once I've done that, I call the method to add the resume attachment to the above list items.

```
AddNewAttachment(intIDs);
    
private void AddNewAttachment(List<int> NodeIDs)
{
    string destUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;
    SPSite rootSite = new SPSite(destUrl);
    SPWeb site = new SPSite(destUrl).OpenWeb();
    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    SPList myList = site.Lists["Candidates"];

    if (fileMUpload.PostedFile != null && fileMUpload.HasFile)
    {

        Stream fStream = fileMUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;

        byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
        fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
        fStream.Close();
        fStream.Dispose();

        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileMUpload.PostedFile.FileName);

        foreach (int NodeID in NodeIDs)
        {

            SPListItem myNewItem = myList.GetItemById(NodeID);
            SPAttachmentCollection attachments = myNewItem.Attachments;

            attachments.Add(fileName, contents);

            myNewItem.SystemUpdate();
            myNewItem = myList.GetItemById(NodeID);
        }
    }
}
```